# how to make urllib.request append to an existing file?

Tags: python

I'm trying to download a load of text in Python and want it all to save to a single file.

The code I'm currently using creates a separate file for each url. It loops through an archive of urls, requests the data and then saves it to its own file.

```
filename = archive[i]
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, path + filename + ".pgn")
```

I've tried using the same filename for each url but it just overwrites the file.

Is there a way to loop through the archive and, rather than saving the data in its own separate file, add each block of text to a single file? Or do I need to just loop through all the files afterwards and concatenate them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's [urlretrive](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) docs says that

> If you wish to retrieve a resource via URL and store it in a temporary location, you can do so via the urlretrieve() function

so if you wish to append the retrieved data in one file you have use [urlopen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) for that

Like [this](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/urllib2.html#fetching-urls) :

```py
import urllib.request

filename = "MY_FILE_PATH"
#-----------inside your i loop-------------
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
    data = response.read()
    # change your file type according e.g. "ab" for binary file
    with open(filename + ".pgn", "a+") as fp: fp.write(str(data))
```

Comment: That's really helpful, thank you! I had to make it ```data = response.read().decode("utf-8")``` otherwise I got \n rather than new lines.

Comment: glad it helps you...^_^

Answer (score 1):

Note that `urlretrieve` [might become deprecated](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/urllib.request.html#legacy-interface) at some point in the future. So use `urlopen` instead.

```
import urllib.request
import shutil

...

filename = archive[i]
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(filename, 'ab') as out_file:  
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
```